# How to set up reusable text string in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, web, razor

How to set up reusable text string in MVC.

for example: i have a text need to use in few pages, how i going to setup.

in PHP is like

```
$lang = array (
    'getpassword' => 'Forget Password',
    'login_guest' => 'No Account？',
    'new_password' => 'New Password',
    'new_password_confirm' => 'Comfirm Password',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare dictionary in view and can use in view

```
 @{
    var lang= new Dictionary<string, string>();
    lang.Add("getpassword", "Forget Password");
    lang.Add("login_guest" , "No Account？");
    lang.Add("new_password", "New Password");
    lang.Add("new_password_confirm", "Confirm Password");
                
                
    var item = lang.Where(x=>x.Key=="getpassword").Select(p => new Dictionary<string, string>() { {p.Key, p.Value }});
    }
```

or you can create one partial view which will declare this dictionary and you can include that partial view in Layout so that you can access it anywhere.

Refer https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1113158/MVC-Reusable-Components

Comment: Sorry may i know how to use it? Because in PHP just <span>{lang.getpassword}</span>

Comment: You can use it by using var item = lang.Where(x=>x.Key=="getpassword").Select(p => new Dictionary<string, string>() { {p.Key, p.Value }});  You just have to change key in where clause